# Changing value of text field referenced in another class results in error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to change value of a text field that is in another class but I keep getting the error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

1st class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Class1 : MonoBehaviour {

Class2 class2;

private void Start()
  {
    class2 = new Class2();
    class2.setText();
  }
}
```

2nd class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Class2 : MonoBehaviour {

public Text txt;

public void setText()
  {
    txt.text = "Sample text";
  }
}
```

The thing is I have got no clue how to make 'txt' visible inside method, it's like the function ignores that it was declared inside second class.

Here are the editor properties of my script component for Class2:

[image: Text connected to script in unity]
[image: Objects Hierarchy]

Comment: `public Text txt = new Text();`

Comment: You're instantiating a `MonoBehaviour` using `new` when you use `class2 = new Class2();`. You can't do this - you'll run into all kinds of reference problems, because that's not have Unity objects are used. You should probably be using `Instantiate()` for this sort of thing. Is the `Text` component on the same GameObject as the `Class2` component?

Comment: @Igor I'm getting this 'Text.Text()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: Asking again, because there's not enough information to supply a proper answer: Is the `Text` component on the same GameObject as the `Class2` component? Furthermore, does the GameObject containing `Class2` already exist in the scene and you're trying to get a reference to it, or are you trying to create a new instance of an object with `Class2` on it? Both of these points are essential to clarifying the situation.

Comment: @Serlite Component with Class2 is on another GameObject, I provided screen to clear things out, this time I did it properly. I think :) Thanks for editing!

Both GameObjects exist from the start

Comment: Alright, thanks for the additional information - added an answer, let me know if anything's unclear about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is that you're trying to get a reference to an existing GameObject with `Class2` on it, but you're using `class2 = new Class2()` to get it. This won't give you the reference you want, and using the `new` keyword with `MonoBehaviour` classes will almost always result in puzzling errors, because that's not how they were designed to be instantiated.

In this case, you don't even want to instantiate an object with `Class2` - there's already one in the scene! You seem to already know how to drag references onto public fields in the Unity editor - just make your `class2` field public, and drag the "GameObjectText" object onto it in the same way:

```
public class Class1 : MonoBehaviour {

    public Class2 class2; // Drag onto this field in the editor

    private void Start()
    {
        class2.setText();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: That helped me a lot!
I'm sorry for not providing proper informations at the start. It's hard when you're newbie and you don't really know what informations are important and which not :)

I surely will need some help soon but I'm always trying my best to find solution by myself but this time i was struggling with that for way too long considering simplicity of this problem :)

Once again huge thanks for help!

Comment: Glad I could help. it takes a bit of time getting used to some of these Unity-specific tricks - just keep at it!

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because in your code you have never assigned a Text GameObject to the Class2 instance, besides that, you are not supposed to instantiate MonoBehaviours like that (see Serlite's comment).

Comment: So, while using :MonoBehaviour it is forbidden to use 'new'? 
Mind telling me how should i replace this "class2 = new Class2();"?

Also, I made it work somehow by adding 
txt = GameObject.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
line in setText function. But I believe it's bad solution, is it?

"Text" is name of text gameobject in unity*

Comment: Sorry for the late response and I see that Serlite gave you in the meanwhile a proper answer, so I have nothing to add on that issue. 

But just keep in mind, in Unity3d everything follows the concept of GameObjects being composed by Components (this includes Scripts/MonoBehaviours), this allows the Editor to be super user friendly towards artists/non-coders. 

And ultimately it's the reason why all public fields in a script are drag-and-drop from the Editor.